# Validations for QR code obtained

Tags: android, validation, qr-code, zxing

I am able to scan and obtain a QR code using ZXING. Based on the QR code obtained, I would like to navigate to a website if it is a URL or add to the contacts if its a contact detail. Are there any functions available in ZXING to do validations on the scanned QR Code?

Answer (score 1):

Most definitely. Within `core/` look at `ResultParser` (see http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk%2Fcore%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fzxing%2Fclient%2Fresult) This is where a raw result string is parsed into something structured. The Barcode Scanner source code in `android/` has even more code that then ties in these results to platform actions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.androidtest&hl=de
Somewhat beta, but should help you.

---

Oh sorry, now I got it. Basically a QR-Code is just a String with some fancy stuff arround. If your App scans a QR-Code via xzing, you should only get the information without the fancy stuff. But if its an URL or a Contact or something else you have to decide yourself programatically, because you can store every kind of information inside a QR-Code.

Comment: Not quite, the library will also parse the string for you into a structured object.